# Anaconda Navigator: installing tensorflow remains "solving package specifications"

Tags: python, tensorflow, package, anaconda, navigator

I want to install the tensorflow DL-package via Anaconda Navigator. It remains on "solving package specifications" status.

Is installing via `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` doing the same thing or is it different from installing via Navigator GUI?

I have already installed `keras` and `keras.preprocessing` via Navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it takes a little time to install a package. So you can wait or can check the internet connectivity while installing tensorflow using Anaconda Navigator.

The second way - You can open Anaconda Command prompt and type below command which will install tensorflow in your conda environement.

`!pip install tesnsorflow`

Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) for your reference.